# ARIMA model not accurate prediction

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, statsmodels, arima

i am trying to predict the next values in a time series using the ARIMA model.
Here is my code:(sorry for the typos)

```
split_val = floor(len(data_file)*0.8)
train = data_file[["Daily Confirmed"]][:split_val]
tesst = data_file[["Daily Confirmed"]][split_val:]

print(train.head())
print(tesst.head())

p = d = q = range(1, 5)

pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q))
# print(pdq)
bestvalues = {}
for i in pdq:
    try:
        p, d, q = i
        moodel = ARIMA(train, order=(p, d, q))
        trained_model = moodel.fit()
        bestvalues[trained_model.aic] = i
        print(trained_model.aic, " ", i)
    except:
        continue

print(bestvalues)
minaic = min(bestvalues.keys())


moodel = ARIMA(train, order=bestvalues[minaic])
trained_model = moodel.fit()

pridiction = trained_model.forecast(steps=len(tesst))[0]

comparisionn = tesst.copy()

comparisionn["forcastted"] = pridiction.tolist()
comparisionn.plot()

print(comparisionn)
print(trained_model.aic)
plt.show()
```

(the data is pre-processed)

The minimum aic i can get is`2145.930883796257` and here are the predictions against the test data (only first 5):

```
            Daily Confirmed    forcastted
Date                                     
2020-06-22            13560  15048.987970
2020-06-23            15656  15349.247935
2020-06-24            16868  15905.260648
2020-06-25            18205  16137.086959
2020-06-26            18255  16237.232886
```

and here is the plot

[image: Plot image]

as you can see, the prediction is not accurate and i have brute forced all the values for p, d and q upto 4....

What might be the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Should i try a different model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get better results if you update your model "daily". Your model hasn't seen any data after July 21st while it may be August 14th. ARIMA may struggle predicting 20-30 steps ahead. Instead - try forecasting step by step, like this:

```
history_endog = list(train.copy(deep=True))
y_true = []
y_pred = []

for obs in test: 
    model = ARIMA(endog=history_endog, order=(p,d,q))
    model_fit = model.fit()
    forecast = model_fit.forecast()[0]

    y_true.append(obs)
    y_pred.append(forecast)
    history_endog.append(obs)
```

Then plot `y_true` and `y_pred`, your results should improve. Code sample above uses lists for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! But this combined with brute forcing all the p,d q values takes tons of time on slower machines. is there any way to make it more efficient ?

Comment: But even though the graph looks much acurate, tha aic is still near 2000...
Any way to improve that?

Comment: @psycoxer the optimization algorithm indeed takes some time. These are not neural networks on GPUs after all. Secondly, you may look for ARIMAX. X stands for exogenous variable, if you choose it correctly it should help. Thirdly, why AIC? Try using something like MAPE on test dataset, imho it is much more straightforward to understand